# SecureString password from C# to PowerShell with ProcessStartInfo

Tags: c#, powershell

In my C# (.net core 3.1) code I want to launch a PowerShell script with several arguments.

The part of my code that creates the ProcessStartInfo looks like this :

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            Arguments = "-NoProfile -NonInteractive -File " + powerShellScriptPath + " -login " + login + " -password " + password + " -server " + server,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        };
```

I would like the password to be secure because I have a warning in PowerShell that tell me to use Secure string.

At the moment my password is just a string and inside the powershell script I use:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
```

Is there a way to do the convert to secure string in the C# code and to directly pass the secure string password to the powershell script ?

Thank you

Comment: [`SecureString` should not be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

Comment: Agree that SecureString should not be used. But wouldn't that mean that the password is forever viewable in Task Manager (the CommandLine Column)?

Comment: That is inherently a shortcoming of any process that passes credentials on the command line. Papering things over with `SecureString` won't help. The `CredentialManager` module can be used to store credentials without exposing them. Alternatively, standard input can be used, or the credential can be written to a secured file and only the path passed (where the script should immediately delete the file after accessing it).

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I posted below my solution with the standard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I don't use SecureString anymore, now I use the standard input, here's the C# code:

```
// your init code

//Create the process
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "powershell.exe",
    Arguments = EscapeCommandLineArguments(cmdLine),
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};

var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo,
};

// your code including process.start

// Write the password to the standard input
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);

//end of your code
```

and in the ps1 script I get back the password:

```
# Read the password on the standard input    
[string]$pass = Read-Host
# do what you want with the pass and then erase it will $null
$pass = $null
```

I hope it will help some of you.